# How to open excel file as readonly without any alerts and without using any path or file name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, macros

I'm loading data into excel template stored in server and downloading it using FileStreamResult. I want to download the excel as read only. To make read only as I tried path is asking but I don't know where the user can download it into his system from server. So, how can I make the file read only?
I'm able to download as read only but it was asking prompt like "Do you want save changes or open as Read-Only?" I don't want that prompt and file to be open directly with Read-Only.

I tried using macro 
But it is asking prompt to save changes.
As I don't know the path as user will download from server to his particular location. So, how can I make that read Only without using path r filename?

Controller:
    System.IO.Stream spreadsheetStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(Server.MapPath("~/XlsReport/Report_Template.xlsm"));
.....(Loading data into worksheets)...

```
wb.SaveAs(spreadsheetStream);
spreadsheetStream.Position = 0;
return new FileStreamResult(spreadsheetStream,"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") { FileDownloadName = "Report.xlsm" };
```

Macro:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly   
End Sub
```

The downloaded file is asking to save changes. It should be directly open as ReadOnly without any prompts.

Comment: *Don't* run Excel on the server. It's definitely *not* meant to work on the server. Your code would start a new Excel instance for each request and unless you take care to close the app and dispose the object properly, you'll leave ghost instances open, eating up memory until the server freezes.

Comment: You'll also have to buy a license for each one of your site's users. `xlsx` files are zip packages containing XML files anyway. You don't need Excel to read or write them. You can use the OpenXML SDK or libraries like Epplus to read and write Excel files. You can also install  the Jet OLEDB driver and treat Excel as a database

Comment: Can you [format your code](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) please. It is a better visual for other and helps for a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I used 
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly

Now the downloaded file was directly opening in read only.